# Cannot change directory using os.Chdir()

Tags: windows, go, cd, chdir

os.Chdir() in golang is not working properly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    command := "cd C:\\"
    if err := os.Chdir(command[3:]); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:\tCould not move into the directory (%s)\n")
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Error:   Could not move into the directory
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: permission problem maybe

Comment: can you show the original error message?

Comment: You should add `, err` at the end of the `Println` arguments

Comment: Chdir takes a directory name as an argument, not a shell command. The error will tell you there is no directory named "cd C:\".

Comment: @Peter: That's not it! The code `os.Chdir(command[3:])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have minimal, reproducible example. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Here is a minimum, reproducible example for your code, discarding all but essential code and printing input, output, and errors.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Getwd())
    dir := `C:\`
    if runtime.GOOS != "windows" {
        dir = `/`
    }
    err := os.Chdir(dir)
    fmt.Println(dir, err)
    fmt.Println(os.Getwd())
}
```

Output:

Windows:

```
C:\Users\peter>go run chdir.go
C:\Users\peter <nil>
C:\ <nil>
C:\ <nil>
C:\Users\peter>
```

Linux:

```
$ go run chdir.go
/home/peter <nil>
/ <nil>
/ <nil>
$
```

It works.

Run it and compare it to your code.